# Record field overwriting other fields

Tags: freepascal

I'm writing an [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer)/input library for my game in [Free Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Pascal), and I'm facing an issue.

I've got a variant record that, when I access an element of it, changes the other elements.

The record type is:

```
tInput = Record
    case Device: TInputDevice of
        ID_KeyOnce, ID_KeyCont:                     (Key:         TSDLKey);
        ID_MouseButton:                             (MouseButton: Byte);
        ID_MouseAxis, ID_JoyAxis,
          ID_JoyBall, ID_JoyHat:                    (Axis:        Byte);
        ID_JoyButton, ID_JoyButtonOnce, ID_JoyAxis,
          ID_JoyHat, ID_JoyBall:                    (Which:       Byte);
        ID_JoyButton, ID_JoyButtonOnce:             (Button:      Byte);
```

end;

The code that crashes it is:

```
with Input do begin
    Device := ID_JoyAxis;
    Which  := 0;
    Axis   := 1;
end;
```

When axis is set to one, all of the other variables in the record go to one two!

Is this a known bug? Or some functionality I'm not aware of? Or something I've screwed up?

Comment: Do you have more details about TSDLKey?`Is it an enum type or rather a class instance? ...

Comment: Okay, cool then my updated answer reflects exactly the state your union should be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a union and intended behavior of this type of record declaration.

```
case Device : TInputDevice of
```

... is the "magic" here.

In a union the storage of members is "shared".

Edit: taking the record you have in terms of byte offsets (... under the assumption that `sizeof(TSDLKey) = 4`):

```
------------------------------------------------
00 | Key | MouseButton | Axis | Which | Button |
---|     |-------------|------|-------|--------|
01 |     |             |      |       |        |
---|     |-------------|------|-------|--------|
02 |     |             |      |       |        |
---|     |-------------|------|-------|--------|
03 |     |             |      |       |        |
------------------------------------------------
```

By the rules I know, TInputDevice should be an enum type, otherwise you'd have to explicitly give `Integer` there:

```
type xyz = record
  case integer of
  0: (foo: Byte);
  1: (bar: Integer);
end;
```

**NB:** it is customary for variant types to have one member describe which of the union members should be picked and valid (nested unions).

Comment: So - this behaviour doesn't change even if you (like me) have duplicate labels? I have to keep them completely separate and rename the similar members?

Comment: I'll edit my reply and try to make it more visible (code formatting in comments is not possible) ...